# What docker fluentd does this command line mean?

Tags: docker, fluentd

I am studying docker fluentd. That is what I do not understand.

```
-v $(pwd)/fluent.conf:/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf \ 
-e FLUENT_CONF=fluent.conf \
```

I don't get the meaning of commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-v` represents `volume` which means you are mounting (attaching) a file from the host file system to the internal docker file system.

`-e` represents `environment` which is simply setting the `FLUENT_CONF` variable to `fluent.conf` which you mounted from your host file system with the `-v` argument.

In that case in order to change configuration you'll have to edit the file `fluent.conf` which resides on the same directory you're running this command from and possibly relaunch the container (either restart or recreate it).